# Calculating IRR for several investments over several years

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am attempting to calculate IRR for 40 or so investments across 2+ years. Very few of them have actualized returns, most of the them have an updated valuations, some of them are now write offs, and for the more recent investments there are no updates. I am having difficulty finding out how to calculate IRR for multiple investments over several years.

My data is as such:

| Date of Investment | Contribution | Current Valuation | Profit/Loss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3/3/2019 | $100000 | $150000 | $50000 |
| 5/6/2019 | $50000 | $55000 | $5000 |
| 10/9/2019 | $25000 | $425000 | $400000 |
| 1/2/2020 | $50000 | $0 | -$50000 |
| 8/9/2020 | $150000 | $225000 | $75000 |
| 2/4/2021 | $300000 | $300000 | $0 |
| 6/7/2021 | $12000 | $120000 | $0 |

Would appreciate any and all insight here! Thank you in advance!

Comment: What excel formulas have you tried exactly? You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Ive tried the IRR formula.

Comment: Try the manual formula in this article and see if it helps and see if you can adapt it (set NPV = 0 in the formula) ..... https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/irr.asp

Comment: Yeah, Ive tried this. Unfortunately, I could not make it work. Thanks though

Comment: Provide specifics on what you tried by editing your question

Comment: Also check your basic formulation of terms. The comment I posted is standard IRR that can be used separately from Excel.

Comment: Computing IRR for individual rows is straightforward. Your problem may be visualizing this calculation for your entire portfolio. The main thing would be to add a new column that imputes a value for that particular row to your portfolio. this new column would use the IRR formula for each row, with 1) the current value of the entire portfolio, 2) the date row, 3) the contribution amount row, and 4) a plug interest rate (same for all rows). To figure out the imputed interest you can manually increment it, and compare the total of the imputed rows to your total portfolio value. Or use solver...